# Visual Studio Editor : Always Add new line of code at Ending of existing lines

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I am struggling with visual studio editor, I've one WinForm (Visual Studio 2015 Comm) App that I am maintaining from last couple of years, after all the improvements and bug fixes the code behind reached to around 2000 lines. 
Issue is If I am adding any new code inside that it places the code anywhere in middle of any other events like If I've added a radio button and want to have click event then if I generate it it places it on 1560th line. (Just an Example).

So Is there any setting for editor that if any new code is getting generated it should always put that on the ending of the existing code like on line 2001?

I am not aware of any such settings but suggestions are needed

Thanks.

Comment: If you mean the event handlers should add after all existing code, yes, it will be added there. It's the default behavior. But if you mean by dropping a new control, it should be added at the end of designer generated code, it's not possible.

Comment: @RezaAghaei yes i knw its default behavior but somehow it is not happening :(